# Spring Data MongoDB does not see accessor for private field from parent class

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Wither
class A {
 protected final List<String> list;

//constructors
}

@Document
@Getter
@Setter
@Wither
class B extends A{

}
```

In this case, class B gets persisted but when I try to read the document from the Mongo database, i'm getting the following exception: "No accessor to set private final A list"
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Without masses of knowledge of Spring Data MongoDB, I would assume that the `list` field probably needs to be marked as `protected` rather than `private` for it to be visible to the subclass.

`protected` makes a field visible to its enclosing `class`'s subclasses, whereas `private` means that only the class itself can see it.

Comment: You're right :) but still it doesn't work. Updating question to have protected instead of private